# Pyspark tumbling window from last movement

Tags: python, pyspark

If I have users with movements across all the year I want to create windows of 30 days to aggregate the data starting from the last movement he did.

So if I have a user with movements on dates:

| id | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-30 | 2 |
| 1 | 2021-02-01 | 4 |
| 1 | 2021-02-08 | 7 |
| 1 | 2021-04-15 | 23 |

I want to create:

```
[window 3, from 01/15 to 02/15]
[window 2, from 02/15 to 03/15]
[window 1, from 03/15 to 04/15]
```

And I almost got it with:

```
    dfsp.groupBy(["id", F.window("date", "30 days")])
        .agg({'value':'sum'})
        .orderBy("window")
        .fillna(0)
```

But I noticed that the windows it generates doesn't start at the end, and I don't know how that can be done.

So, basically, the final dataframe would be something like:

| id | window | sum(value) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | (2021-01-15 00:00:00, 2021-02-15 00:00:00) | 13 |
| 1 | (2021-02-15 00:00:00, 2021-03-15 00:00:00) | 0 |
| 1 | (2021-03-15 00:00:00, 2021-04-15 00:00:00) | 23 |

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve something close to this using [applyInPandas](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.applyInPandas.html) and [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html). In native Spark it would require more creative coding.

Note: `orgin='end'` parameter of resample is only available pandas >= 1.3.0

```
df = df.withColumn('date', f.col('date').cast(TimestampType()))

def pd_resample(df):
    return df.groupby('id').resample('30D', on='date', origin='end').value.sum().reset_index()

schema = StructType([
    StructField('id', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('date', TimestampType(), True),
    StructField('value', IntegerType(), True)
])

df.groupby('id').applyInPandas(pd_resample, schema=schema).show()

+---+-------------------+-----+                                                 
| id|               date|value|
+---+-------------------+-----+
|  1|2021-02-14 00:00:00|   13|
|  1|2021-03-16 00:00:00|    0|
|  1|2021-04-15 00:00:00|   23|
+---+-------------------+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks, I suppose I can work with this. I'm working in an old EMR cluster (5.27), so the latest version I can use of pandas is 1.0.5. But I suppose I can try to download the data and install pyspark in my computer to do this.

Comment: If the data volumes are small enough to run locally then Spark might not be the right tool for the job (depends on what you mean with 'my computer'). You can simply do it in pandas directly.

Comment: Well, is to create a test dataset for churn rate, so I'm only working with around 5kk rows, the real dataset is much bigger, but maybe I don't use them all. But my PC has 64gb RAM & 16CPUs, so I suppose I could create the demo dataset there, and if I proceed with it see how I can do it with the whole dataset, maybe they upgrade the EMR cluster before that xD